# What is the equation to calculate the CurrentGroup

Tags: math, equation

Trying to figure out an equation to get the current group a page would be in if they were grouped like below.

Variables:

```
PageSize = 5
PageIndex = 21
GroupSize = 5
TotalItems = 1000
CurrentPage = PageIndex + 1
```

Find:

```
**CurrentGroup = ?**
```

If there are 1000 items and you have a group size of 5 then there are 200 groups (TotalItems / GroupSize).  This means that CurrentPage 22 must land in group 5

```
Group 1: 1 2 3 4 5
Group 2: 6 7 8 9 10
Group 3: 11 12 13 14 15
Group 4: 16 17 18 19 20
Group 5: 21 22 23 24 25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula

```
1+floor((CurrentPage-1)/GroupSize)
```

Test

```
1 -> 1 
.. 
5 -> 1 
6 -> 2 
.. 
9 -> 2
..
22 -> 5
```

Comment: Or, simpler formula: ceiling(CurrentPage/GroupSize). Easy to prove that the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you were asking --

Assumes integer math:

```
 page = ( item / ItemsPerPage ) + 1; // depends if 0 based.
 pageIndex = item % ItemsPerPage;
 group = ( page / GroupSize );
```

*Page* is the page you're seeking

*pageIndex* is it's position on the destination page

*group* is the actual group it fits in based on GroupSize

In essence, you're just adding another level of paging so the same math works as paging.